# Device or resource busy - getaddrinfo

Tags: centos, dns, hosts

I'm on a CentOS 7 VM running PG, MariaDB, sidekiq and apache httpd. Sometimes my logs are spammed with  errors such as:

```
unable to resolve address: System error

WARN: Mysql2::Error::ConnectionError: Unknown MySQL server host 'mariadb' (16)

WARN: PG::ConnectionBad: could not translate host name "postgres" to address: System error

WARN -- : Unable to record event with remote Sentry server (Errno::EBUSY - Failed to open TCP connection to o383708.ingest.sentry.io:443 (Device or resource busy - getaddrinfo)):
```

All these hosts (except the sentry service) are set to 127.0.0.1 in my /etc/hosts file.

Pinging the host names appears to work from the console, these errors pop up in various application logs during runtime.

lsof | wc -l => 700k (max 1.6M)

The VM is under no significant load (10% load average). No attacks or rootkits or anything like that.

My hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

127.0.0.1 mariadb
127.0.0.1 postgres
127.0.0.1 mongodb
127.0.0.1 redis
127.0.0.1 memcached
127.0.0.1 socketcluster
```

Contents of /etc/nsswitch.com

```
passwd:     files sss
shadow:     files sss
group:      files sss

hosts:      files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files sss

netgroup:   nisplus sss

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files nisplus sss
aliases:    files nisplus
```

Anyone know what's going on? Why can't getaddrinfo open the hosts file???

Adding a bounty to this question. Please no freeloading.

Comment: you need to show us details of your /etc/hosts and configuration for mariaDB and postgres

Comment: I've added the hosts file above, pretty straightforward. Don't see how the server configs for maria and postgres can affect the host name not resolving, if that's what you meant?

Comment: Well IP connection is always made by address (name or IP) and port (I wonder on what port you are running the services and if you can connect when you have this message at the log).  What is the order you lookup the names?  hosts,dns, etc.?

Comment: If you look closer at the error messages you'll notice the host cannot be found despite it being correctly configured in the hosts file, and not an error regarding authentication, port filtered, daemon not running and so on.

Comment: Please show the permissions of the /etc/hosts file: `ls -l /etc/hosts`

Comment: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 568 May 24 13:10 /etc/hosts

Comment: What are the contents of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`? This is where name resolution is handled.

Comment: It's the default that comes with centos, I've pasted the file contents above (minus the comments to save space)

Comment: Interesting.  How do you come to the conclusion that getaddrinfo can't open the hosts file?  From what you posted, I can see two failures to resolve hostnames, but nothing about failure to open the hosts file; also, is that sentry error related?  (Looks like "no" and that it has to do with the `o383708.ingest.sentry.io` server instead, but I'm not certain and perhaps you included the error for a reason?)

Comment: You evidently checked `lsof` to see if the total max file descriptors might be exceeded, but what about per-process limits?

Comment: I thought that since the definitions are in the hosts file it can't open it. Now that you mentioned it I guess it could be something else considering it can't resolve a remote host as well (the sentry host). About per process open files - none of the applications opens a lot of files or sends a lot of requests, some are quite short lived like simple rake tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are onto the right root cause with discussion of `/etc/hosts`.  The fact that some of these *failing* domains are configured correctly in hosts *and* hosts is first in `nsswitch.conf` suggests that the failure occurs before / during opening `/etc/hosts`.

---

Your first hurdle is to reproduce the problem at the command line.

I would investigate whether or not these services are running in a [mount namespace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/mount_namespaces.7.html).  I read somewhere that Centos uses more mount namespaces for it's services.  I vaguely remember the reason being that it changes something in `/etc/` but I could be completely wrong.  So for mariadb check if the output of these three match:

```bsh
# systemd
ls -lh /proc/1/ns/mnt
# console 
ls -lh /proc/self/ns/mnt 
# mariadb / mysql
ls -lh /proc/$(pidof mysqld)/ns/mnt
```

If mariadb doesn't match your console then it's in a different namespace.  You should be able to enter that namespace with:

```
nsenter -mt $(pidof mysqld) /bin/bash
```

This will let you investigate further what's going on.  Hopefully it should give you a command line that experiences the same problems as mysql.

*Note* if the problem is temporary, then you will need to do this during an "outage".

---

The next step is to hunt for what exactly is failing.  At the moment we're guessing that it's `/etc/hosts` but there are other files read before that.  The really useful command for this is [strace](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html)

If you can reproduce the error on the command line then use strace with a simple command.  Eg if you can get a ping command to fail then take a look at the output file generated by:

```
strace -o output_file ping mariadb
```

If you can't reproduce the error then you could strace mariadb itself.  The output file of this will be monumentally large, but might give you something to work with

```
strace -o output_file -p $(pidof mysqld)
```

---

Once you have the strace output you can search it for the exact system call which failed and the context.  Based on your error message you are looking for [EBUSY](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html):

```
grep -nC5 EBUSY output_file
```

This will give you the system call that failed and 5 lines either side for good luck.  It may take a little forensic work, but it should tell you exactly what's getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by having only 4096 inotify handlers. I've increased the limits and the issue is gone.

```
fs.file-max = 131070
fs.inotify.max_user_watches = 65536
```

Comment: If both of your questions can be answered by this, aren't they basically the same question? Should we close one as a duplicate of the other?

Comment: Possibly. At the same time, two different questions regarding different issues with different symptoms can have the same answer. I leave that for the community to decide.